# Can't watch videos online - gets "loading the player " and nothing happens

Tags: google-chrome, flash, safari, flash-player

I'm having a problem trying to see sports highlights. On chrome and safari, I get the message "loading the player..." while nothing happens.

I've tried to reinstall the flash player, chrome, and shockwave and nothing changed.

How can I identify the player which won't load? How can I reinstall it ?
I'm using macbook pro late 2011 and this site is an example for the problem -

[One sports](http://www.one.co.il/Cat/Video/)

Comment: Are you having this problem on multiple sites (e.g. Youtube, Vimeo, etc.), or just one site? There are a number of things that could go wrong, and it could well be the website itself.

Comment: Try a different browser

Comment: "Loading the player..." refers to JW Player on that site. Disable all add-ons except Flash and try again.

Comment: i have disabled the add-ons and still "loading the player..". @karan

Comment: I tried with a different browser and got the same result, but from other computers it works fine. @ParthianShot